# net : ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED

Tags: angularjs, node.js, google-chrome, express, angular-services

hi I have been facing a problem in chrome. I don't know if it is my code fault or the chrome fault. And the error is

**Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**

my **QSTNURL** is
`const app = angular.module('myapp',["ngRoute"]);` `app.value("QSTNURL","https://localhost:12345/api/insertQuestion");`

**my controller.js from client side is**

```
app.controller('myctrl',function($scope,userFactory,QSTNURL){
  $scope.pushData = function(){
  var qstn = $scope.qstn;
  var opt1 = $scope.opt1;
  var opt2 = $scope.opt2;
  var opt3 = $scope.opt3;
  var opt4 = $scope.opt4;
  var ans = $scope.ans;
  const qstnObject = {
      "qstn":qstn,
      "opt1":opt1,
      "opt2":opt2,
      "opt3":opt3,
      "opt4":opt4,
      "ans":ans
  }
  console.log('doAjax');
  var promise = userFactory.doAjax(QSTNURL,qstnObject);
  promise.then(function(response){
      $scope.data = response;
   },function(error){
      $scope.error = error;
  });
 }

});
```

And my ajax call to server is

```
app.factory("userFactory",function($http,$q){
  var userObject = {
    doAjax(QSTNURL,qstnObject){
        console.log('doAjax()');
            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http.get(QSTNURL,qstnObject).then(function(response){
                defer.resolve(response);
                console.log("doAjax 2");
            },function(error){
                defer.reject(error);
            });
            return defer.promise;

    }
  };
   return userObject;
});
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
 var expressSession = require('express-session');
 const app = express();
 var path = require("path");
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 const userRoutes = require("./routes/userroutes");
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
 app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

 app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
 app.use(expressSession({secret: 'mySecretKey'}));

 app.use('/api',userRoutes);

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());


 app.use('/',userRoutes);
 app.listen(12345,()=>{
 console.log("Server Start...");
});
```

**my all the static files(like:- all js files to make SPA e.g. app.js, controller, facotry etc.) are in public folder and view part in views folder**

my routes code is

```
router.get('/insertQuestion',(req,response)=>{
  console.log("insertQuestion");
  var qstn = req.body.qstn;
  var opt1 = req.body.opt1;
  var opt2 = req.body.opt2;
  var opt3 = req.body.opt3;
  var opt4 = req.body.opt4;
  var ans = req.body.ans;
  var qstnObject = new Insert(qstn,opt1,opt2,opt3,opt4,ans);
  userOperation.insertQuestion(qstnObject,response,req);
  response.json("question inserted");
});
```

Comment: is server running? May you call the rest point from browser via link for example?

Comment: yes server is running...I can do login and registration

Answer (score 0):

This error only happens if you have no server running on the 12345 port.

You are calling `https://localhost:12345/dashboard/insertQuestion`. So you should also consider that you are using `https` scheme so make sure your server supports https scheme and port is proper.

If you haven't configured your node app/server app to run on https then just replace

```
https://localhost:12345/dashboard/insertQuestion
```

with

```
http://localhost:12345/dashboard/insertQuestion
```

Comment: sir how could I send `https` request to the server. and server is running properly on port 12345 that's why I am able to do login and registration. Server starts properly.I think problem is in http request.

Comment: That's what I am saying that you are sending request to https url but if your server is running on local than it might be running on http. Editing the answer

Comment: when I replaced `https` with `http` then error changed to `GET http://localhost:12345/dashboard/insertQuestion 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: yeah that means you have error on your server logic and request get passes through. Check the server logs for a better overview of an error. Your question is resolved by the way.

Answer (score 0):

hey I got the answer the whole problem was in the QSTNURL. I should not have passed this URL`https://localhost:12345/api/insertQuestion` while pass only `api/insertQuestion` directly to the AJAX call like this

```
app.factory("userFactory",function($http,$q){
var userObject = {
doAjax(QSTNURL,qstnObject){
    console.log('doAjax()');
        var defer = $q.defer();
        $http.get('/api/insertQuestion',qstnObject).then(function(response){
            defer.resolve(response);
            console.log("doAjax 2");
        },function(error){
            defer.reject(error);
        });
        return defer.promise;

}
};
return userObject;
});
```

I don't know why it is so. but It removed my problem

Comment: There's no reason to use the `$q` service here. Just return `$http.get()`. It's already a promise erroring and resolving to the same values.